# JQuery Fade Navigation with Background Image. Image won't fade, text will

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, hover, background-image

I am trying to use a smooth JQuery fade class-swap effect on my navigation. My problem is that the fade effect only works on the text, not the background image. How can I get the background image to fade in and out with the text upon hover?

My CSS:

```
#nava {
  text-align:center;
  width: 170px;
  height: 110px;
}

.style1 {
  background-image: url(buttons/home_off.png);
  background-size:170px 110px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width: 170px;
  height: 110px;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.style2 {
  background-image: url(buttons/home_on.png);
  background-size:170px 110px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width: 170px;
  height: 110px;
  display: block;
  color: #4DAC61;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

My JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nava a").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).switchClass('style1', 'style2', 200);
  });

  $("#nava a").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).switchClass('style2', 'style1', 600);
  });
});
```

My HTML

```
<div id="nava">
  <a class="style1" href="index.html"><br /><br /><br />HOME</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle. You've obviously created your own method called `.switchClass()`, it would help to see that code, as well.

Comment: @DevlshOne is `.switchClass()` not part of the jQuery UI library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/

> Not all styles can be animated. For example, **there is no way to animate a background image**. Any styles that cannot be animated will be changed at the end of the animation.

ps: you can place two elements, one over another (one transparent and another not), and change their opacity simultaneously. For an example - http://jsfiddle.net/23HAU/

CSS:

```
.style1 {
    background: url(image1.jpg);
}
.style2 {
    background: url(image2.jpg);
    display: none;
}

.style1, .style2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
   <div class='style1'></div>
   <div class='style2'></div>
```

And jQuery code:

```
   $('.style1').fadeOut(2000);
   $('.style2').fadeIn(2000);
```